# Copy relative paths of some files and other files in subdirectories to a text file

Tags: powershell, cmd, relative-path

I have a folder named **source**. It has some jpeg files and some subdirectories containing further jpeg files. I want to copy relative paths of all the files and other files in subdirectories in a text document "test.txt". For example,
I have files,

```
a.jpg
b.jpg
c.jpg
```

and subdirectories

```
sub1/d.jpg
sub2/e.jpg
```

I want to copy the relative paths of all these with respect to the current folder I am in(just outside source)

The output I want is:

```
source/a.jpg
source/b.jpg
source/c.jpg
source/sub1/d.jpg
source/sub2/e.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a shorter way (especially with the two replace), but this should help:

From inside the source folder:

```
(gci -recurse *.jpg|Resolve-path -relative) -replace "\\","/" -replace "[.]/","source/" > test.txt
```

From the folder containig the source folder:

```
(gci -recurse "source\*.jpg"|Resolve-path -relative) -replace "\\","/" -replace "[.]/","" > test.txt
```

`gci` is an alias for `Get-ChildItem`

Comment: Where have you specified the "test" text file to store the output?

Comment: @pulp_fiction Updated the answer, just redirect the output to a file with `>`

Comment: Okay, I tried it and Nope. It does produce an empty text file named test but thats it.

Comment: @pulp_fiction Please try step by step, i.e. what do you get for `gci -recurse *.jpg`, what do you get for `gci -recurse *.jpg|Resolve-path -relative` and so on. The solution works for me, hard to tell from the distance what your problem is.

Comment: Okay I have figured it out. Your solution perfectly works but from inside of the folder in which there are images actually present. I mean, if I execute the script from inside of the **source** folder, it lists the images. But, I was looking for a little twist - I am(My script) in the folder containing the **source** folder. From here I want to be able to specify the name of  source folder and "list the relative.......inside the test.txt located where the script is" hope you get me.

Comment: Okay I have finally made it. I am Powershell "**illiterate**" actually. All I had to do was specify -path flag and it worked finally. Thank You.

Comment: Nope! Your updated version doesn't work, I don't know why. I had done a different change. Here it is, (gci -path source -recurse *.jpg|Resolve-path -relative) -replace "\\","/" -replace "[.]/","source/" > test.txt    which works

Answer (score 1):

For those, Ocaso Protal's answer(It deserved the correct checkmark because it is correct indeed) doesn't work,(though it should, but didn't for me so I tweaked it a little) here is my tweaked version.

```
(gci -path source -recurse *.jpg|Resolve-path -relative) -replace "\\","/" -replace "[.]/","source/" > test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If the path separator is not a requirement, just for the `cmd` tag in the question, you can directly use this, but the path delimiter will be a backslash, not a slash

```dos
xcopy /l /s "source\*" "%temp%" | find "\" > test.txt
```

**edited** to adapt to comments

I am not sure this is not an aberration (powershell is not my area), but ...

```dos
xcopy /l /s "source\*" "%temp%" | find "\" | powershell -c "$input -replace '\\','/'" > test.txt
```

Comment: That's a problem. I need the slash not the backslash because the software that is gonna process it works with the slashes. If somehow the backslashes be replaced by slashes...

Comment: Also, I ran your command in cmd, it returned find: invalid argument

Comment: @pulp_fiction, answer updated. Sure someone will find a better way of doing it.

Comment: @pulp_fiction, for me, the windows native `find` command is working. Maybe you have another version in your path. Try with `"%windir%\system32\find.exe"`

Comment: I tried your edited version and it seems to get struck in an infinite loop. After a long time waiting, when I pressed ctrl+c, it displayed **FIND: Parameter format not correct**

Comment: @pulp_fiction, please, execute `where find` to see which `find` version you are using.

Comment: @pulp_fiction, i have to say i don't know why you get the parameter error. Tested on XP and 7 and it works. The only way I'm able to get the error is removing the quotes around the backslash.